# Using two data sources in a single PerformancePoint KPI/scorecard

Tags: performancepoint

I already have a scorecard and now I want to add another target metric to one KPI, and I want the target values to be pulled from a SharePoint list, so they are easily accessable.

Is it possible to make another data source play nicely with the dimensions and filters from another (which is already used in the scorecard)?

Comment: Is this PerformancePoint Server 2007, or PerformancePoint Services in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this.  You should try to pull your targets & actuals into the same data source; I would do this with a View in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this through [Custom filter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg410936.aspx)

Link the cube dimensions in the custom filter table and then you can use single filter for values in the scorecard that come from different datasources.